# When std::thread is destructed and what happen to the shared_ptr if the pointer point to it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, stdthread

When I create a std::thread instance, when will it be destructed? Is the time when the thread finish its task then it is destructed or it works as a normal object which will be destructed when it will not be used anymore?

```
//a fake function for std::thread
void func();
void main()
{
    auto threadPtr = std::make_shared<std::thread>(func)
    threadPtr->join(); 
    // is thread object which threadPtr point destructed in here ? 
    //... other stuffs ....    
}
```

Is thread object destructed after `threadPtr->join()`?

Comment: There's no other code sharing that thread instance, so it will be merely the same if it's simply allocated on the stack.

Comment: Why do you think the thread object was destroyed?

Comment: `threadPtr` is destroyed when you leave main, just like any other stack variable.

Comment: So std::thread object will be destructed as a normal object. It will not be destructed when it finish its task, correct ?

Comment: @buddha _"It will not be destructed when it finish its task, correct ?"_ Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

> Is thread object destructed after `threadPtr->join()`?

No.  `join()` ends the thread of execution that the `std::thread` object represents, it does not destroy the `std::thread` object.

> When I create a std::thread instance, when will it be destructed?

It will be destroyed when `threadPtr` goes out of scope since it is an automatic object(it has [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)).  The `std::shared_ptr` destructor will call the `std::thread` destructor, and then it will free the memory it obtained.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying operating system thread may have terminated but that isn't the same as the C++ `std::thread` object being destructed.

Execute the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

std::mutex cout_mutex;
std::atomic<bool> waiter{true};

void func(){
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << "funky\n";
    }
    while(waiter);//cheap spin waiting...
}

int main() {

    auto threadPtr = std::make_shared<std::thread>(func);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << "an active thread id: "<<threadPtr->get_id()<<'\n';
    }
    waiter=false;
    threadPtr->join();
    std::cout << "terminated thread id: "<< threadPtr->get_id()<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output varies but possible output here is:

```
an active thread id: 47441922455296
funky
terminated thread id: thread::id of a non-executing thread
```

The object contained in `threadptr` remains valid until destructed but may be referencing a terminated thread.

`std::thread` is typically an implementation of a wrapper class (or the proxy design pattern). It contains a (possibly empty) reference to what is normally an operating system thread object. When the wrapped thread ends the reference may be made empty.